# What type of ads are these? iAds/Admob?

Tags: swift, admob, iad

I'm trying to add ads into my app, however, there's so much to choose from. Any idea if these ads are from iAds/Admob?  They're pretty good at giving 'relevant' ads, so I'm trying to implement this one. Some of them are full pages too, which I like.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do believe that is AdMob. I've had a lot of success using it in my apps, one of the better networks. Another good one is ChartBoost (pretty quick and easy setup, supports full screen still and interactive ads)